# What's the current status of the P.SE blog?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, blog

Activity for our blog was great initially, however it died down a month or two ago and never seemed to recover.

I know at the time of writing this question, there is 1 post done, 2 being reviewed, and 3 being written, however that list has not had a changed in over a month.

Is the Programmers blog currently not going to happen?

I am asking because I am the author of the post which is done, and wanted to post the article on my own blog. I had planned on waiting until it posted to the P.SE blog so I could provide a link to it as well, however I've been waiting for a few months now and the situation doesn't seem to be changing anytime soon.

Comment: I would Go ahead and post it on your blog..

Comment: WOOOOOOOOOOOOO! [status-completed]!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Party!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Morons O ye, of little faith...

Answer (score 3):

**Launched!**

Now go [read it](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/)!

Comment: Perhaps you should include a link to the blog here? :)

Comment: @Rachel Yannis beat me ;P

Comment: Thanks for all your hard work to make this happen Jae :)

Comment: @Rachel Thanks :-)